# How to get the sum of a list of numbers excluding integers that are divisible by 3 and 7 with recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to find the summation of integer in list with elements that are divisible by 3 or 7 excluded

```
def SumSkip37(numList,sum = 0):
    if numList:
        i = numList.pop()
        if i % 3 == 0 or i % 7 == 0:
            return sum
        else:
            sum += i
            return SumSkip37(numList, sum=sum)



numList = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
print(f'The result is {SumSkip37(numList)}.')
```

Pls help me figure out

Comment: Must you really use recursion? Also isn't it an issue to mutate the input?

Comment: This is an assignment. I have to use recursive function

Comment: Although you have to use recursion for the assignment, it's good to also learn the more pythonic way, **and** you can use it to test that your recursive function gives the same result as the simpler version, `sum(i for i in numList if i % 3 != 0 and i % 7 != 0)`

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend **not** calling a variable `sum` in python. Avoid naming variables with names from that list: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Answer (score 2):

You can update your code to:

```
def SumSkip37(numList, my_sum = 0): # avoid using sum
    if numList:
        i = numList.pop()
        if i % 3 == 0 or i % 7 == 0:
            return SumSkip37(numList, my_sum=my_sum) # pass the unchanged sum
        else:
            return SumSkip37(numList, my_sum=my_sum+i) # pass the sum + i
    else:
        return my_sum
```

*NB. I tried to stay as close as possible to the original, but you can simplify greatly!*

To avoid mutating the input:

```
def SumSkip37(numList, my_sum = 0):
    if numList:
        if numList[0] % 3 != 0 and numList[0] % 7 != 0:
            my_sum += numList[0]
        return SumSkip37(numList[1:], my_sum=my_sum)
    return my_sum
print(f'The result is {SumSkip37(numList)}.')
```

Better approach than the alternative above suggested by @Stef to run in linear time:

```
def SumSkip37(numList, my_sum=0, idx=0):
    if idx >= len(numList):
        return my_sum
    elif numList[idx] % 3 != 0 and numList[idx] % 7 != 0:
        return SumSkip37(numList, my_sum + numList[idx], idx + 1)
    return SumSkip37(numList, my_sum, idx + 1)
```

Also, recursion is overkill here, better use a short generator expression:

```
sum(i for i in numList if i%7!=0 and i%3!=0)
```

Comment: Calling `numList[1:]` at each iteration makes the algorithm quadratic instead of linear. How about adding an integer index instead? `def SumSkip37(numList, my_sum=0, idx=0): if idx >= len(numList): return my_sum elif numList[idx] % 3 != 0 and numList[idx] % 7 != 0: return SumSkip37(numList, my_sum + numList[idx], idx + 1) else: return SumSkip37(numList, my_sum, idx + 1)`

Comment: @Stef you're right, let me update!

Comment: That's one more argument against using recursion in python - not only is there no tail-call optimisation and are function calls particularly slow, but the data structures are not suited for the usual patterns that we see in recursion in other languages, such as making a recursive call on a sublist. (in fact I hesitated before posting my first comment, because although using numList[1:] is bad in python, the equivalent would be good in any language where recursion is good)

Answer (score 0):

On relatively clean way:

```
def SumSkip37(numList):
    if not numList:
        return 0
    head, *tail = numList
    return head * bool(head % 3 and head % 7) + SumSkip37(tail)
```

Comment: Guess what the result of your solution will be for `[10]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You just weren't iterating through the whole list:

```
def SumSkip37(numList, total=0):
    if numList:
        i = numList.pop()
        if i % 3 != 0 and i % 7 != 0:
            total += i
        return SumSkip37(numList, total=total)
    return total
```

I flipped the comparison to remove the unnecessary `else` branch. It doesn't matter if the current number is divisible with 3 or 7 or not, you always want to continue the recursion until the list runs out.

Answer (score 0):

Without Recursive function:

```
def SumSkip37(list):
    sum = 0
    for i in list:
        if i % 3 == 0 or i % 7 == 0:
            continue
        else:
            sum += i
    return sum

list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(SumSkip37(list))
```

With Recursive Function:

```
def SumSkip37(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        if lst[0] % 3 == 0 or lst[0] % 7 == 0:
            return SumSkip37(lst[1:])
        else:
            return lst[0] + SumSkip37(lst[1:])

print(SumSkip37([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
```